Javascript problems with on click functionality and output on page
I am working on an internet page (first time learner) and I am struggling with on click on element to show something on page.
So I have this in my HTML
<body>
    <div class ="content">
        <ul class="options">
            <li id="o1">option 1</li>
            ...
        </ul>
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>

So I have one div element which has 2 elements in it - a table with n li (each with id="ox") and a div where I, with on click on the element in table it has to be written what I have clicked.
here is my javascript
let selector = document.querySelectorAll('.content .options li');
let writer = document.querySelector('.content .result');
console.log(writer);
selector.forEach(
    ()=>{
        addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    }
);

function clickHandler(){
    writer.innerHTML = '...';
}

The problem is I don't know what is wrong (from the fact I don't know how to make output of which element I have clicked on (like for 'option 1'  to write 'option 1' etc.)).
But even if I don't do that and just make it to print anything random, it still doesn't show anything!
And I have searched for an answer, but I still couldn't make it function.
The only thing that also comes to my mind, would it be a problem if I in CSS used a grid for this div (content), but I don't see why would that influenced the JavaScript. And yes, I have linked HTML with javascript.

selector.forEach(()=>{ addEventListener('click', clickHandler); } this is not how you add an eventListener to elements in js, no wonder is not working. Change your forEach syntax, it should look like this selector.forEach((element) => { element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler); )}

The forEach() callback should have a parameter for the current item in the iteration, and add the event listener to that. addEventListener by itself is equivalent to window.addEventListener
The listener function gets an event argument, from which you can get the element that was clicked on.


let selector = document.querySelectorAll('.content .options li');
let writer = document.querySelector('.content .result');
//console.log(writer);
selector.forEach(
  (li) => li.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
);

function clickHandler(event) {
  writer.innerHTML = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;
}
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="options">
      <li id="o1">option 1</li>
      <li id="o2">option 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="result"></div>
  </div>
</body>




I see your code works wonderfully well, unfortunately, I don't know why I can't see the output. Maybe the linking is the problem.

What linking are you referring to?

Because I have separate document for js, I have to in html doc have link it somehow (sorry my terminology regarding js is lacking, I am not well informed) and I did that incorrectly, but afterwards when I fixed that issue, this worked perfect

You're talking about <script src="filename.js">? The important thing is that this must be at the end of the body, not before it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Yeah, now I know. Thanks for the link, I appreciate it.
